# Файлы в билде Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Собираются ли в .apk файл файлы, которые не были использованы ни в одной сцене, но при этом есть в проекте? Просто появилась проблема с слишком большим весом билда и хотелось бы конкретнее узнать на, что обратить внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У юнити есть официальный пакет Build Report Inspector, который позволяет узнать информацию как о стадиях сборки билда, так и об ассетах, вощедших в билд. Сам покет пока в виде превью, но уже может быть полезен. Информацию о нем можно глянуть [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.build-report-inspector@0.1/manual/index.html)
2. Есть сторонний плагин [Build Report Tool](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/build-report-tool-8162), который также позволяет узнать, что попало в билд. Проверен временем и многим пользователями, правда не бесплатный.
3. Еще один плагин [Better Build Info](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/better-build-info-report-tool-70329), также не бесплатный.
4. Можно посмотреть Editor.log - лог файл редактора юнити. При сборке туда пишется вся информация о билде и файлы и исходники и сколько они заняли. Вся информация в текстовом виде и представляет собой большое полотнище, но при желании покопаться можно. О том, как найти лог файл можно прочитать в [официальном мануале](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html).

Немного общей информации: при сборке юнити включает в билд следующие ассеты:

- те, на которые есть ссылки в сценах, которые вы включили в Build Settings
- все ассеты без разбора, которые лежат в папке Resources (во всех папках Resources, которые есть в вашем проекте).